# Handling missing fields when using Python lambda's

Tags: python, lambda, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I have this rethinkDB query which basically returns the documents which "basicConstraints" fields that start with "CA:FA".

However in some of my documents the "basicConstraints" field does not exist.

```
q = r.db('scanafi').table(active_table) \
.concat_map(lambda doc: doc["certificates"]\
.concat_map(lambda x: x["parsed_certificate"]["X509 extensions"])\
    .filter(lambda x: x["basicConstraints"]
.match("^CA:FA"))) \
.run()
```

How can I also include all of the documents which contain this missing field in my query?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `x` doesn't have methods like a regular python dict (I'm not familiar with rethinkdb).  You could just use a real function here, with a try/except clause:

```
def basic_constraints(x):
    try:
        return x["basicConstraints"]
    except:  # find out what the actual exception is and put that here
        return True

q = r.db('scanafi').table(active_table) \
.concat_map(lambda doc: doc["certificates"]\
.concat_map(lambda x: x["parsed_certificate"]["X509 extensions"])\
    .filter(basic_constraints)
.match("^CA:FA"))) \
.run()## Heading ##
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So I tried that but it throws the following error: `.filter(lambda x: x["basicConstraints"] if "basicConstraints" in x else True
TypeError: argument of type 'Var' is not iterable`

Answer (score 0):

You can write `x.has_fields('basicConstraints').not().or_(x['basicConstraints'].match("^CA:FA"))`.